# 12V Signal -> Relay -> Voltage Regulator -> Arduino mega analogue input. Will this work?

Tags: arduino, relay, input

[image]I have a system that sometimes generates a 12V signal to a DPDT relay coil, which switches on a 12V connection through the relay pins that can be used as a boolean signal to the arduino. I plan to do this by connecting a 5V L7805 regulator, followed by a 1n4007 diode to drop the voltage to approx 4.3V +-10% which should be safe.

My question is, should I be concerned about inductance from the relay coil? I know arduinos don't like inductive loads. Also, are any additional resistors necessary in this configuration, i.e. with the arduino i/o pins configured as inputs with pullup resistors?

If you can foresee any problems with this setup, please let me know.

Comment: Please put together a schematic using the CircuitLab tool. I think your circuit will be fine but a schematic will improve answers and suggestions.

Comment: If it is a Boolean signal, don't use an analog input.

Comment: Bit Heath Robinson this - this is the one situation where it's OK to use a voltage divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with the 7805 - without input and output capacitors this could prove problematic and, at the very least will be "slow" in responding to the 12V input.

Just use a resistor and 4.3V zener diode like this: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9WA6A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You don't need to worry about glitches either because the relay coil is isolated from the Arduino by the relay contacts.

Comment: +1 This circuit also puts a reasonably high current through the relay contacts (12mA) which is often required for reliable switching. I'd stick a 1K in series with the input just for luck.

Comment: How would it prove problematic without the input and output capacitors? I understand it would be more stable with less ripple if you added the input and output capacitors as is recommended in the l7805 datasheet, and I did consider it. But problematic? Also, are there any distinct advantages to using your circuit? edit: Regarding response time, how much lag on an order of magnitude would you estimate? Milii/Micro?

Comment: Problematic: it might oscillate. My circuit is smaller, cheaper and the lag will be in the order of a few nano seconds. You could even get rid of the relay and use the output from keyswitch S2 directly. Also, a 1N400x into an open circuit will not drop any voltage - it requires current flow to drop voltage.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv4Zru.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay contact driving micro-controller.*

> My question is, should I be concerned about inductance from the relay coil?

No. There is no connection between the coil and the digital input. Therefore there is no danger of inductive transient to the input.

> I know arduinos don't like inductive loads.

But you aren't *driving* the relay - you are monitoring a contact of it.

> Also, are any additional resistors necessary in this configuration, i.e. with the arduino i/o pins configured as inputs with pullup resistors?

If you use the internal pull-up you can just use the relay contact to pull the input low when closed.